# css position fixed to a location within an area

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making an list of products in a shop website using asp.net and html. 
my Items are showing up alright, But i don't like the look of the button being misaligned depending on the prodcut name length.

[image]

i am trying to keep the details button fixed at the bottom regardless, like the box like it is on product 1,3 , and 5. 
The other products' names push the text down.

these are my css in question.

```
#GameCatalogue
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
#GameCatalogue li {
    /* http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ */
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 320px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 5px;
        zoom: 1;
        *display: inline;
        _height: 250px;
        border-radius: 7px;
}

.detailsButtom{
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
/* i tried, vertical-height, alignment, position fixed, absolute, messed around with z-index,  as well as moving the items in different locations through my li containter. 
}
```

and this is my output html (for 1 item)

```
<li>
<div class="img">
<img alt="" src="../Images/mariou.jpg" id="Graphic1"> 
</div>
<div class="info">
<h3 id="Name" 1'="">SuperMario U</h3>
<p id="Descr1" data-description="Super Mario u is the latest installment of the classic mario franchise. up to 5 players simultaniously can traverse a vast world spanning over 90 unique levels.">
Super Mario u is the...</p>
<div class="price"><span class="st">Our Price:</span>
<strong id="price1">$45.99</strong>
</div><div class="actions"><a href="#details_popup" style="position: relative;top: 25px;" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-prodcd"1"="">Details</a></div></div></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, please notice that the CSS code you've posted doesn't fully match the DOM that you've posted (in the DOM you have no element with the `detailsButtom` class).

---

To achieve what you want, you need to set `position: absolute` for the element you want to "stick" to the bottom.
Then you need to set its container's [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to be `position: relative`. Now you can set the coordinates of the inner element as you wish (with these attributes: `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`).

---

So, set the `.detailsButtom` (Should be written *bottom*) class likewise:

```
.detailsButtom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0; /* You can change these values */
}
```

and set the container's class to be (I assume it's the li in your CSS):

```
#GameCatalogue li {
     position: relative;
}
```

---

### Further Reading

1. [CSS Tricks - Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)
2. [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: @173901 You're welcome. Also notice that I've added more information to my answer.

Comment: thanks i browsed over those links. you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` for parent elements and use `position:absolute` for children elemenst that we want change positioning manually. When we use the `position` attribute, we must be sure that uses one of these groups:

1. `top`, `left` attribute
2. `top`, `right` attribute
3. `bottom`, `left` attribute
4. `bottom`, `right` attribute

Please do not use (`top`, `bottom`) and (`right`, `left`) attribute simultaneously.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. You can work magic with using them simultaneously. For example http://jsfiddle.net/AThTK/